# How many questions in the site till now?

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow is an awesome site where I find my 80% of my programming clarifications.

So I was thinking about this site, and I found in a day (24 hrs) about 8-10k questions are being asked. It would be cool to know till this date:

how many questions have been asked (*Might be millions or billions*) and of them, how many are answered?

So we get the rating of our technical site.

Comment: Go to [so]. Click on the "Questions" tab. Look to the right.

Comment: Unfortunately that no longer works.

Comment: Now, go https://data.stackexchange.com/  lists *all* SE sites, each with # Qs & As.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: All questions]

[image: Unanswered (no up voted)]

[image: Unanswered (no answer)]

Comment: -1, this is out of date, there are 7,706,762 questions..

Comment: wait now there are 7,706,767

Comment: As I pointed out [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266332/how-many-questions-are-on-stack-overflow#comment65141_266334), this does not, of course, include deleted questions. I think Shog mentioned somewhere that when you include those, the total number of questions that have ever been asked is around 9 million.

Comment: what is this? its empty. did something happen? links are broken?

Answer (score 12):

You need to query online to obtain the number of questions:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/849225

Or, go to this address:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

and type the following query:

```
select count(*) as count 
from posts 
where postTypeId = 1
```

and then run it.

If you want the answers, change the postTypeId to 2.

As of now (2018-May-08), it gives me approximately 15.8m questions and 24.5m answers.

Comment: that is only non deleted questions, use postswithdeleted to find the number of ever asked questions.