# If the parent question is deleted, should the duplicate flag not be removed?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Looking at this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266701/stackoverflow-how-many-questions-in-the-site-till-now), I can't see the parent question. Should the duplicate flag not be removed, if the original question is removed?

Answer (score 3):

Deletion like that isn't possible in the first place, but maybe it was, back then.

The dupe closure is pointless, if the target is deleted.

Since the question is no longer a duplicate, I've taken the liberty to re-open the question.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that question can be reopened immediately. I think high reputation perks :)

Comment: I don't think it's that a case of "it was allowed back then" - I suspect it's because the owner of the duplicate question's account was removed and since it was negatively scored - the Community bot is a little overzealous in clearing up posts... probably similar to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote

Comment: @JonClements I think [since 2015-01-30](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/165773) nobody can delete dupe target, neither Community bot nor moderators

Comment: @WaqasBukhary: More or less: Because I have a [gold `[discussion]` badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/discussion?userid=1835379), I can single-handedly re-open `[discussion]` duplicates. So it's not _just_ reputation.

Comment: @gnat I've certainly see prompts as a mod when trying to delete a post that's a target dupe so that's definitely a case. I'm fairly sure the user deletion process is a bit more laissez faire in regards to what it does though...

Comment: @gnat Auto-deletions upon user deletion still do not consider post state. The Community user will still delete a question with duplicates pointing at it so long as it is negatively scored. However, we have since changed the system so negatively scored questions on Meta are just not deleted at all on user deletion.